# I have heaps of redundant code. The set of letters come in the json file and i want to parse whatever is there

Tags: java, android, data-structures, android-uiautomator

```
    package automate;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice;
    import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

    public class AlphabetGestures extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
        private static Map<Character,Vector<Point>> map = new HashMap<Character,Vector<Point>>() ;
        private static JSONObject jsonObj;
        static{
               String text;
               try {
                       File file = new File("/data/misc/alphaNums.json");
                       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                       byte[] data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                       fis.read(data);
                       fis.close();
                       text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                       jsonObj = new JSONObject(text);
                   } catch(JSONException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

/*I am not able to implement the following algorithm:-
I want to create a map for all the characters <- already there in the static bloc
    open the alphaNum.json file <- already there in the static bloc,but not error handling.
    parse it as a json object <- already there in the static bloc,

```
for every letter in the json object {
  create a vector<Point> 
  for every Point in the letter {
    add the Point to the vector
  }
  add the vector to the map
}
```

*/

```
        Vector<Point> liA = setupA();
        Vector<Point> liB = setupB();
        Vector<Point> liC = setupC();

        map.put('A',liA) ;
        map.put('B',liB) ;
        map.put('C',liC) ;
    }


    private static Vector<Point> setupA(){
        try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("A");
        System.out.println("IS here");
        //get array A
        if(jsonArr!=null){
        Vector<Point> apoints = new Vector<Point>();
        System.out.println("IS here");
        for(int k = 0; k < jsonArr.length(); k++ ){
        JSONArray arr = jsonArr.getJSONArray(k);
        apoints.add(new Point(arr.getInt(0), arr.getInt(1)));
        System.out.println(apoints);
        }return apoints ;
        }else{
        System.out.println("A is null");
        }
        } catch (JSONException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Vector<Point> setupB(){
        try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("B");
        System.out.println("IS here");
        //get array B
        if(jsonArr!=null){
        Vector<Point> apoints = new Vector<Point>();
        System.out.println("LUMIA IS here");
        for(int k = 0; k < jsonArr.length(); k++ ){
        JSONArray arr = jsonArr.getJSONArray(k);
        apoints.add(new Point(arr.getInt(0), arr.getInt(1)));
        System.out.println(apoints);
        }return apoints ;
        }else{
        System.out.println("B is null");
        }
        } catch (JSONException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Vector<Point> setupC(){
        try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("C");
        System.out.println("IS here");
        //get array C
        if(jsonArr!=null){
        Vector<Point> apoints = new Vector<Point>();
        System.out.println(" IS here");
        for(int k = 0; k < jsonArr.length(); k++ ){
        JSONArray arr = jsonArr.getJSONArray(k);
        apoints.add(new Point(arr.getInt(0), arr.getInt(1)));
        System.out.println(apoints);
        }return apoints ;
        }else{
        System.out.println("C is null");
        }
        } catch (JSONException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void scribble(char letter, UiDevice uiDevice){
        System.out.println("here");
        Vector<Point> points = map.get(letter) ;
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println(points);
        if(points!=null){
        uiDevice.swipe(points.toArray(new Point[points.size()]), 5);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample JSON file, please? I have difficulty visualising exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @KenY-N following is the contents of json file....
{
"A": [[150,450],[150,150],[250,150],[250,450],[250,275],[150,275]],

"B": [[140,537],[140,538],[140,539],[140,541],[140,543],[140,547],[140,552]],

"C": [[232,552],[232,551],[231,551],[230,550],[223,549],[217,547],[210,546],[202,545],[187,544],[175,544],[162,544],[147,547],[122,556],[114,562],[111,566],[103,576],[95,589],[89,606],[86,654],[93,670],[105,686],[126,705],[144,713],[165,717],[189,718],[221,711],[234,705],[243,700]]
}

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
private static Vector<Point> setupLetter(String letter){
    try {
    JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray(letter);
    System.out.println("IS here");
    //get array corresponding to letter
    if(jsonArr!=null){
    Vector<Point> letterPoints = new Vector<Point>();
    System.out.println("IS here");
    for(int k = 0; k < jsonArr.length(); k++ ){
    JSONArray arr = jsonArr.getJSONArray(k);
    letterPoints.add(new Point(arr.getInt(0), arr.getInt(1)));
    System.out.println(letterPoints);
    }return letterPoints ;
    }else{
    System.out.println("%s is null".format(letter));
    }
    } catch (JSONException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Where is it giving you NULL? Are you passing in an appropriate letter?

Comment: It does not take any letter and just simply returns null....yes,i am passing "C" !

Comment: All I did is take your code literally and generalize it. If it isn't returning what you want, then there's something wrong with your code. Is an exception occurring in the try/catch block? What is the exception if so?

Comment: the above code with all the vectors and map....it works fine whenever it receive a letter from scribble method....but instead of writing vector and map for all the alphabets...i want to write a single function that can parse every letter and i dont have to write same thing....in your code it does not take the letter...and i am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: The above code with all the vectors and map should be changed to `Vector<Point> liA = setup("A"); map.put('A',liA);` etc, to work with the function I have written. Take out all the setupA, setupB, setupC stuff. Have you done that?

Comment: Vector<Point> liA = setupLetter("A");  instead of Vector<Point> liA = setup("A");

Comment: "Vector<Point> liA = setup("A");" was never even there. I can't debug this for you over stackoverflow. You need to put breakpoints in your method and see where things are failing. That being said, if the original `setupA()` working then my method SHOULD work, but like I said, I can't debug this for you...

Comment: hey....it works...there was some problem in the device....it was not able to find the path of the file